# Android Facebook api 3.0 error: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, tabactivity

I am trying to integrate an android app with the the new facebook 3.0 api, but I get this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {dk.imu.konnekt/com.facebook.LoginActivity}:
>   com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null
>   calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is
>   singleInstance.

I have search for this error but no one else seems to have had any troble with it. I guess it is because I am using a TabHost and TabsGroupActivities for each tab. But I have no clue on how to solve it.

I have added the relevant code here:

```
public class MainTabActivity extends TabActivity {    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanteState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanteState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_layout);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        View shareTab = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.share_tab, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Share").setIndicator(shareTab)
        .setContent(new Intent(MainTabActivity.this, ShareGroupActivity.class)));

        ...
    }
}
```

-

```
public class ShareGroupActivity extends TabsGroupActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startChildActivity("ShareActivity", new Intent(this, ShareActivity.class));
    }
}
```

-

```
public class ShareActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.share);

        testFacebookConnection();
    }

    public void testFacebookConnection(){
        Session session = new Session(this);
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        SessionState state = session.getState();

        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = 
            new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                Toast.makeText(ShareActivity.this, "Facebook session status changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }
        };

        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed() && session.getState() != SessionState.OPENING) {
            OpenRequest open = new OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback);
            List<String> permission = new ArrayList<String>();
            permission.add("publish_actions");
            open.setPermissions(permission);
            session.openForPublish(open);
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Any clue on how to solve it?

**Update 1 stack trace:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume
>   activity {dk.imu.konnekt/com.facebook.LoginActivity}:
>   com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null
>   calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is
>   singleInstance. at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2851)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2234)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null
>   calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is
>   singleInstance. at
>   com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:110) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1236)
>   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4613) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2796)
>   ... 12 more

**Update 2:**
I looked through the code and found the implementation of startChildActivity:

```
public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {     
   Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
   if (window != null) {
       mIdList.add(Id);
       setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
   }    
}
```

It uses the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. I tried to remove it, but no change in the outcome.

**Update 3:**

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/LoginActivity.java

The Facebook code uses

```
callingPackage = getCallingPackage();
```

and

```
if (callingPackage == null) {
       throw new FacebookException(NULL_CALLING_PKG_ERROR_MSG);
}
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingPackage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingPackage%28%29)

This method has a note:

> If the calling activity is not expecting a result (that is it did not
>   use the startActivityForResult(Intent, int) form that includes a
>   request code), then the calling package will be null.

In the method startChildActivity I use the getLocalActivityManager().startActivity, in TabsGroupActivity that extends ActivityGroup, to handle tab activities.
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html#startActivity(java.lang.String, android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html#startActivity%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.Intent%29)

This method does not what the notes says. It does not expect a result and does not use the startActivityForResult method. The method also ensures something similar to singleinstance launchmode.
How should I change this method implementation, so it can work with facebook?

Comment: `the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance`

Comment: any singleInstance activity in all that ?

Comment: I haven't specifically assigned any activities to singleInstance. But I guess that the tabhost maybe makes every child tabgroupactivity singleInstance by default. Any idea where to check that - or mabye change it..?

Comment: Se update - it uses the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?  I am experiencing the same error, though it is when explicitly finishing an Activity that is opened from another Activity that uses a Facebook login - the Facebook related Activity comes back to top and this error is thrown.  Hoping they are related...

Comment: this is not much of an solution to the issue, it's more than patch.
i would recommend @Sandro solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots of searching I figured out that there don't seems to be a way to startActivityForResult with LocalActivityManager used in the tabs.

So I ended up accepting that it will need an activity filling the entire screen. The activity is only shown a second or so with good network connection - I have made it with a republish option on errors also..

Start publish activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FacebookShareActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Constants.FACEBOOK_MESSAGE, shareMessage.getMessage());
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Facebook share activity code - publishing to users wall:

```
public class FacebookShareActivity extends Activity {
    String message;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.facebook_publishing);

        message = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constants.FACEBOOK_MESSAGE);
        createFacebookConnection();
    }

    public void republishButton_Click(View view){
        setVisibilityForRepublishButton(false);
        createFacebookConnection();
    }

    public void createFacebookConnection() {
        Session session = new Session(this);
        Session.setActiveSession(session);

        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                String message = "Facebook session status changed - " + session.getState() + " - Exception: " + exception;
                //Toast.makeText(FacebookShareActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.w("Facebook test", message);

                if (session.isOpened() || session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
                    publishToWall();
                } else if (session.isOpened()) {
                    OpenRequest open = new OpenRequest(FacebookShareActivity.this).setCallback(this);
                    List<String> permission = new ArrayList<String>();
                    permission.add("publish_actions");
                    open.setPermissions(permission);
                    Log.w("Facebook test", "Open for publish");
                    session.openForPublish(open);
                }
            }
        };

        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed() && session.getState() != SessionState.OPENING) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Log.w("Facebook test", "Open active session");
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    private void setVisibilityForRepublishButton(Boolean visible) {
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.republishButton)).setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Toast.makeText(FacebookShareActivity.this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    void publishToWall() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("message", message);

        final Context context = this;
        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    setVisibilityForRepublishButton(true);
                    Toast.makeText(context, error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        setVisibilityForRepublishButton(true);
                        Log.i("Facebook error", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    //Toast.makeText(context, postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I managed to find my problem. Although I wasn't setting

android:launchMode="singleTask"

my LoginActivity had

android:noHistory="true"

which results in that exception. I put noHistory true because I didn't want the user to be able to press back button on the first activity after login and go back to login screen. Now I need to find another solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem : trying to log into facebook, with the dialog provided inside the SDK, but from an activity that was itself inside a tabgroup ; like ShareActivity above.

What I've done is basically called startActivityForResult on parent activity of ShareActivity (that is ShareGroupActivity), instead of calling it on ShareActivity.

So 1 , add this in ShareGroupActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.out.println("facebook status called");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

2 you need to modify the class Session, inside FacebookSDK project, under src com.facebook

2.1 add a boolean member

```
public boolean insideTabGroup;
```

2.2 modify StartActivityDelegate, that is used by session to open login ; add the boolean as parameter

```
interface StartActivityDelegate {
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, boolean insideTabGroup);

    public Activity getActivityContext();
}
```

2.3 inside the inner class AuthorizationRequest, modify the implementation of this delegate :

```
    AuthorizationRequest(final Activity activity) {
        startActivityDelegate = new StartActivityDelegate() {
            @Override
            public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, boolean insideTabGroup) {
                if(insideTabGroup) {
                    ActivityGroup parentActivity = (ActivityGroup) activity.getParent();
                    parentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode);

                } else {
                    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Activity getActivityContext() {
                return activity;
            }
        };
    }
```

2.4 Also, modify the other constructors of AuthorizationRequest, by just adding the boolean parameter. As I do not use login to facebook from somewhere else than an activity, that's ok.

2.5 Modifiy the tryLoginActivity method of Session class, to use the boolean member as a parameter :

```
private boolean tryLoginActivity(AuthorizationRequest request) {
    Intent intent = getLoginActivityIntent(request);

    if (!resolveIntent(intent)) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        request.getStartActivityDelegate().startActivityForResult(intent, request.getRequestCode(),this.insideTabGroup);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

3 Set the boolean member in the session :

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
session.insideTabGroup = true;
```

That should do the trick.

Cdt

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error with the Parse.com Facebook SDK integration and was down to me missing the call to `ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication` which is noted in the [docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers).

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```