# FacebookException : Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting the following error in my google play crash reports.

```
FacebookException : Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance
```

I could not reproduce this issue. Has anyone encountered this issue before and solved it. I am giving the crash report below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.games.mygame/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.
at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:110)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
... 12 more
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am calling my facebook related functions from a singleton class. Can that cause any issues.

Comment: Check it out: [Updated - Android Facebook api 3.0 error: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123580/updated-android-facebook-api-3-0-error-cannot-call-loginactivity-with-a-null)

Comment: @Sajmon i saw that link but could not make heads or tails out of the answer. Can you please explain a bit for me.

Comment: Ask another question that details *specifically* what's confusing for you in the answer to the other question.

Comment: @Shog9 I do not understand whats causing this error in first place as i have not been able to reproduce this issue. This was reported in google play crash reports. And from what i have read in the other answer it has something to do with sharing or activity not expecting result or something. I seriously cant even understand the situation stated in it.