# Facebook for android, why can't I use 'this' as the activity to openRequest()?

Tags: android, facebook

In my activity class I am unable to open a request or set active session using 'this'. My activity is a child of another activity and that seems to be the only difference between it and the login sample given by facebook. When I use 'this' I get this error:

```
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.tsavomedia.babynames/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006): Caused by: com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:110)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
05-24 12:24:27.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30006):    ... 12 more
```

I have tried using getParent() in its place however the page redirects to the parent and does not call the callback. Is there a reason I cannot use this and a way to fix it?

EDIT: code

This is what gets called once the button is clicked to login to facebook:

```
public void getEmail() {
    StatusCallback callback = new StatusCallback() {
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                sendRequests();
            } else if (exception != null) {
                AlertDialog alertDialog;
                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle(getParent().getString(R.string.login_fail));
                alertDialog.setMessage(exception.getMessage());
                alertDialog.show();
                mSession = createSession();
            }
        }
    };
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        session = new Session(this);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED) || session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED)) {
            session.addCallback(callback);
            session.openForRead(new OpenRequest(this));
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
        }
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet ?

Comment: I may be wrong, but an activity as a child to another activity doesn't seem like a good idea. Try using a fragment instead maybe?

Comment: editted post for code

Comment: @l2y-Did you solved this problem..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error log says : ...the caller is singleInstance.

maybe same probleme: [Updated - Android Facebook api 3.0 error: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123580/updated-android-facebook-api-3-0-error-cannot-call-loginactivity-with-a-null)